# Adding a purge command in a discord bot using python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

how do i add a purge command in my bot? here's my hopeless code which of course isn't working, the bot doesn't respond to it

```
@client.command()
async def sc(ctx):
  await ctx.channel.purge
  await ctx.channel.send("Thank you for choosing the wheat farms")
```

my intention is for the bot to purge the entire channel upon receiving the command "/sc"

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what type of questions are allowed here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Do these help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43465082/python-discord-py-delete-all-messages-in-a-text-channel, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63264337/how-can-i-delete-entire-messages-in-a-text-channel-in-discord-with-discord-pytho and https://stackoverflow.com/a/66270058/16136190

Comment: Documentation is your friend! https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=purge#discord.TextChannel.purge. You're probably looking for `limit=whatever`

Comment: You can probably also try deleting all messages after a `datetime`. By getting [the `TextChannel`'s creation date](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=purge#discord.TextChannel.created_at) using `channel_created_at = ctx.channel.created_at`: `await ctx.channel.purge(after = channel_created_at)`. You can delete all the messages after the `TextChannel`'s creation date to clears all messages in it.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing all msgs is not possible so by nuking the channel you do get the same results.

Enjoy!

```py
 @client.command()
 async def sc(ctx):
   channel=ctx.channel
   new_channel = await channel.clone(reason=".")
   await channel.delete()
   await new_channel.send("Thank you for choosing the wheat farms")
```

If this is not what you want you can look into this
[python Discord.py delete all messages in a text channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43465082/python-discord-py-delete-all-messages-in-a-text-channel)

But I would still prefer this method

Comment: That's not a nice way to achieve what the OP wants. Also, I think `channel=ctx.message.channel` should be `channel=ctx.channel`. Deleting the channel would mean you won't have the same channel ID etc. again

Comment: well, @TheAmateurCoder I hope OP doesn't want the id but... discord.py does not support getting the total amount of messages in a channel or such and if you want t do it it is pretty tedious. This is a dirty way to solve it  Here is a similar question it may help him out if needed

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43465082/python-discord-py-delete-all-messages-in-a-text-channel

Comment: That's true, but cloning isn't the best way, though (there's no such 'best' way either). Also, it's better to avoid answering poorly-phrased, duplicate or unclear questions. See meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293931/… and meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368284/…. It's better to comment in such cases. And this method is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66270052/16136190) too. Purging (without deleting) the channel is slow, but deleting would affect many things, like other bots monitoring the channel etc. too.

Comment: You may be right.... lets see